# oracle: Count occurrence of a status in consecutive rows

Tags: oracle, count, rows, varchar

I have a table which stores status of a customer reply in oracle. I have to count last consecutive declines from the customer.

For ex:
Id      Status
-----------------------------
1.      Declined 
2.      Accepted
3.      Declined
4.      Declined

This will have count = 2. 
As last two were declined.

Comment: Does ID indicate order of the records?  Where is the customer ID?

Comment: Yes, Id indicates the order of the record. The data represents only one customer.

Comment: What if you have 3 consecutive declines?

Comment: If there are 3 consecutive declines at the end. The count should be 3.

Comment: And if you have (in order) D, A, D, D, A, A,  then you must count the most recent consecutive DECLINES, regardless of Acceptances at the very end? In this case what is the desired result - 2, or 0 (to indicate the most recent status is Accepted)?

Comment: If most recent is Accepted then answer will be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gurmeet - Then the problem is much easier. Here is one way to solve it. If you need the result ordered by customer_id, add `order by customer_id` right at the end. nvl in the definition of d_A in CTE t2 is needed in case that customer never had a transaction with "Accepted" status.

**Input**:  Same as in my other Answer.

**Query**: (MODIFIED to meet OP additional requirement):

```
    with t0 as (select customer_id, status, row_number() over 
                        (partition by customer_id order by decision_id) rn from t),
         t1 as (select customer_id, max(rn) as d_all from t0 group by customer_id),
         t2 as (select customer_id, nvl(max(rn), 0) as d_A from t0
                where status = 'Accept' group by customer_id)
    select customer_id, d_all - d_A as ct from t1 natural join t2

    /
```

**Result**:

```
CUSTOMER_ID         CT
----------- ----------
         30          0
         10          2

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks so much "MathGuy". This one is correct to an extent. 
It works fine as of now for me. But the problem it subtracts from max id rather than counting.
For ex: if customer_id = 10 and decision_id = 6 row is deleted,
the query will still give result as 2 (7-5) but actually its only 1.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you are saying - in your sample, the "decision" id was sequential, but in real life it may not be. Assuming the rows can still be ordered correctly by the "decision" id, but the decision id is not sequential, this can be fixed. Give me a few minutes to try and come back to you.

Comment: I edited my most recent answer. Please see if it works for you now. row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by decision_id) does exactly what the decision_id was doing in my earlier attempt - it simply numbers the rows in sequential order, no matter what the decision_id numbers are.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:  Original Poster clarified in a "comment" that she needed a different requirement - addressing it in a separate Answer. Keeping this since it shows one possible solution for a more complicated problem that the OP's.

Assuming you want the count of the most recent consecutive "Declines" (even if followed by "Accepted" - and you want to allow for more than one customer - here is one possible solution.

**Input table (I called it "t"):**

```
SQL> select * from t;

CUSTOMER_ID DECISION_ID STATUS
----------- ----------- --------------------
         10           1 Accepted
         10           2 Declined
         10           3 Declined
         10           4 Accepted
         10           5 Accepted
         10           6 Declined
         10           7 Declined
         30           1 Declined
         30           2 Accepted
         30           3 Declined
         30           4 Accepted
         30           5 Declined
         30           6 Declined
         30           7 Declined
         30           8 Accepted
         30           9 Accepted
```

**Query:**

```
with t1 as 
  (
    select customer_id, 
           decision_id - row_number() over 
                             (partition by customer_id order by decision_id) as idx 
    from   t 
    where  status = 'Declined'
  ),
  t2 as (select customer_id, max(idx) as max_idx from t1 group by customer_id)
select t1.customer_id, count(1) as ct
from t1 join t2 on t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id 
where t1.idx = t2.max_idx
group by t1.customer_id
order by t1.customer_id
/
```

**Query output:**

```
CUSTOMER_ID         CT
----------- ----------
         10          2
         30          3
```

Comment: In my case I only want to know the count of declines at the end. For the above case, answer should be: 10 - 2, 30 - 0